# install arch into already parttioned disk

Tags: arch-linux, partition, system-installation

I've been using linux for couple of years, but still can't manage partitioning at all. I have `/` and `/home` partitions on my drive and want to use these partitions for my fresh Arch installation. I'm not good at partitioning from console. So without risking to lose my `/home` data, how can I set it up. I have `sda4` for `/`, `sda5` for `home`, and `sda3` for `swap`.

Comment: This would help you.https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Boot Arch Linux ISO from USB drive.
- Format the partitions if not formatted.
- Initialize swap partition:

```
mkswap /dev/sda3
swapon /dev/sda3
```

- Mount partitions:

```bash
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/home
```

- Check if all partitions mounted correctly with `lsblk` command.
  The output will be something like this:

```bash
# lsblk
    NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    sda      8:0    0  100G  0 disk 
    ├─sda1   8:1    0  512M  0 part 
    ├─sda2   8:2    0    1G  0 part [SWAP]
    ├─sda3   8:3    0   20G  0 part /
    └─sda4   8:4    0   80G  0 part /home
```

- Install base packages: `pacstrap /mnt base`
- Add fstab entries: `genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab`. Also do this for `/home`.
- chroot into new system: `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash`
- Follow the next steps from [Arch Linux installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide).

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOXYZ8hKdmc) for explained instructions.